# Return value for jQuery data method won't convert to Number

Tags: jquery, html

I'm working on a JavaScript calculator and I'm refactoring the code to DRY it out by using the HTML "data" attribute. (I want to have one function for data entry, not ten functions--one per digit--as I had in v1.0.) My goal is to use jQuery to parse an integer from the data attribute, but I've hit a wall.

Here is a row of buttons in HTML:

```
<div class="row" id ="row3">
  <div data-number=“7” class="button number gray" id="seven">7
  </div>
  <div data-number=“8” class="button number gray" id="eight">8
  </div>
  <div data-number=“9” class="button number gray" id="nine">9
  </div>
  <div data-operand="*" class="button orange operand" id="multiply">&times;
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's an event trigger:

```
$(".number").mouseup(pushNumber);
```

And here's the broken function:

```
var pushNumber = function() {
var num =  $(this).data("number");
var parseNum = parseInt(num);
console.log(parseNum);
console.log(typeof num);
}
```

When I click a given button, `console.log(parseNum)` returns "NaN", and `console.log(typeof num)` returns "string". Based on the documentation for jQuery, I believe that .data should return a number here. So, all that said...
1. How can I make sure that .data returns a number, not a string?
2. Why can't I use the parseInt method on num?

Here's the full project: 
https://codepen.io/halfalpine/pen/MeJwmV?editors=1010

I've searched for something relevant to the best of my ability but I've come up short. My apologies if this entry is redundant!

Comment: Side note, you need to fix the typo in the fancy quotes in your HTML. Ex `data-number=“9”`. Actually, that may be the whole problem.

Comment: I think there is a problem with your quotes, they are other kind of character not the real " char

Comment: Don't use a word processor for editing code, use an IDE. It won't make these mistakes.

Comment: @Barmar, I composed the whole thing in CodePen! But I think your point is good to keep in mind nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your fancy quotes, look at your console it's outputing the values with them.

data-number=“8”

Should be

data-number="8"

Comment: @Dirk, Just to add: Because the browser does not recognize those characters as quotes, they are treated as part of the value, so the value is `“7”`, instead of just `7`. That means JQuery will not automatically parse the value to an integer, and you will get `NaN` if you try to parse it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think that JoshBerke's answer "nailed" your actual problem.

But I leave my answer, since it is a simplification of your function.

```
$(".number").on("mouseup", function(){
    var thisNumber = parseInt($(this).attr("data-number")); // Is an integrer here.
    console.log(thisNumber);
)};
```

Comment: Apparently, the .data method can convert to a Number automatically, so now it can be written simply as `var num = $(this).data("number");`

Comment: About `.data()` method, you should read on [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/). This is different from retreiving the value of the `data-number` attribute .